# ng-disabled is not working on span tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There is a span tag with glyphicon icon that I want to disable.But ng-disabled is not working, that is the icon is still clickable.

```
<span ng-disabled="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="font-size:13px;" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="DeleteIpAdress(objIpAdress)" ng-show="objIpAdress.ShowRemoveButton" ng-model="objIpAdress.ShowRemoveButton" title="Delete IP address"></span>
```

Is anything wrong in the tag?

Comment: what do you mean by disabling a span tag ?

Comment: used only to button or form  element  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: ng-disabled="true" ==> $scope.true, so you need set variable $scope.true = true;
and, of course, it's strange, that you disable span tag :D

Comment: if you want set TRUE to ng-disabled, try ng-disabled="'1'" or ng-disabled="" - "" for empty string

Comment: @KoIIIeY, as I remember, you are wrong about assignment. If there is no `true` in scope, it will be the real true.

Comment: I just want to disable the click and make icon to show in disabled mode (light gray)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ng-disabled doesn't work on span.So I disabled the click

```
ng-click="disabledConditionHere || DeleteIpAdress(objIpAdress)"
```

and then changed the style of span by using class

```
.disable-span{
    color: #E6E6E6;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

and used class in span tag

```
class="disable-span"
```

Answer (score 9):

`ng-disabled` directive works only with input fields and buttons. It does not work with span. [Ref: ngDisabled Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

You can prevent click action using following code

```
ng-click="isClickAllowed && DeleteIpAdress(objIpAdress)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem once, from memory the solution is to put the disabled condition in the ng-click.

`ng-click="disabledConditionHere || DeleteIpAdress(objIpAdress)"`

Comment: By this mean i can disable the click, but I want icon to be shown in disabled mode (light gray)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using bootstrap add bootstrap class `btn btn-xs` to the `span` tag. This will fix `ng-disabled` for span tag. Works in firefox.